# Custom adapter update after AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-adapter

All right, I'm getting really confused here.
Here is a little summary of what's happening.

1. I get the user location through GPD
2. In the first IF statement I gather "opzioni" and "images" which I want to feed into my adapter, but I also need a third array whose data I can gather only later on in the script.
3. I gather the coordinates of an element inside the database
4. run an AsyncTask that returns the DISTANCE between user and database element.
5. DISTANCE value is put inside distance Array and the loop goes on five times.

Now the problem that I have is that both "opzioni" and "images" are gathered before the adapter is called while I can access distance data only after every AsyncTask.

I am not able to update the ListView.

This is the source

```
package com.example.myapp;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


//import com.example.nevianoapp.NevianoMapsV2.DownloadTask;
//import com.example.nevianoapp.NevianoMapsV2.ParserTask;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CategoryMenu extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, LocationListener {

    ListView l;
    String[] opzioni;
    int[] images;
    String[] distance;
    String category;
    LatLng myPos;
    LatLng dest;
    String distanceAsync;
    int nextIndex = 0;
    NewAdapter adapter;
    List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> test;


    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.category_menu_layout);

         // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        // Getting the name of the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        // Getting Current Location From GPS
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        myPos = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());


        Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(location.getLatitude())+ " " + String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //for(int x = 1; x < 6; x = x+1) {
        if(getIntent().getIntExtra("str1", 0) == 0){
            opzioni = new String[5];
            images = new int[5];
            distance = new String[5];

            for (int x = 0; x < 5; x = x+1){
            opzioni[x] = db.getCultura(x+1, "cultura").getName();
            images[x] = (R.drawable.cultura);
            dest = new LatLng(db.getCultura(x+1, "cultura").getCoordLat(), db.getCultura(x+1, "cultura").getCoordLong());

            String url = getDirectionsUrl(myPos, dest);
            DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
            downloadTask.execute(url);

            }
        }
        if(getIntent().getIntExtra("str1", 0) == 1){
            opzioni = new String[13];
            images = new int[13];
            for (int x = 0; x < 13; x = x+1){
            opzioni[x] = db.getCultura(x+1, "ristoranti").getName();
            images[x] = (R.drawable.ristoranti);
            }
        }
        if(getIntent().getIntExtra("str1", 0) == 2){
            opzioni = new String[17];
            images = new int[17];
            for (int x = 0; x < 17; x = x+1){
            opzioni[x] = db.getCultura(x+1, "alberghi").getName();
            images[x] = (R.drawable.itinerari);
            }
        }


        l=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);

        NewAdapter adapter = new NewAdapter(this, opzioni, images, distance);
        l.setAdapter(adapter);
        l.setOnItemClickListener(this); 




    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.category_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, informazioni.class);
        category = getIntent().getStringExtra("category");
        i.putExtra("str1", arg2);
        i.putExtra("category", category);

        Toast.makeText(this, "hey " + arg2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();// TODO Auto-generated method stub

        startActivity(i);

    }

     private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest){

            // Origin of route
            String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;

            // Destination of route
            String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;

            // Sensor enabled
            String sensor = "sensor=false";

            // Building the parameters to the web service
            String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor;

            // Output format
            String output = "json";

            // Building the url to the web service
            String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;

            return url;
        }

        /** A method to download json data from url */
        private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
            String data = "";
            InputStream iStream = null;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            try{
                URL url = new URL(strUrl);

                // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                // Connecting to url
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Reading data from url
                iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

                StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";
                while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                    sb.append(line);
                }

                data = sb.toString();

                br.close();

            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
            }finally{
                iStream.close();
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            return data;
        }

        /** A class to download data from Google Directions URL */
        private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

            // Downloading data in non-ui thread
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

                // For storing data from web service
                String data = "";

                try{
                    // Fetching the data from web service
                    data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
                }
                return data;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

                // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
                parserTask.execute(result);
            }
            // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
            // doInBackground()

}

        private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> >{




            // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
            @Override
            protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

                JSONObject jObject;
                List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

                try{
                    jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                    DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

                    // Starts parsing data
                    routes = parser.parse(jObject);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return routes;
            }

            // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(0);
                HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(0);


                        distanceAsync = point.get("distance");
                        distance[nextIndex] = distanceAsync;
                        ++nextIndex;
                        test.clear();
                        test.addAll(result);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

class NewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
    Context context;
    int[] images;
    String[] title;
    String[] subTitle;

    NewAdapter(Context c, String[] opzioni, int[] imgs, String[] distanza){
        super(c, R.layout.single_row, R.id.descrizione, opzioni);
        this.context = c;
        this.images = imgs;
        this.title = opzioni;
        this.subTitle = distanza;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, parent, false);

        ImageView myImage = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        TextView myOptions = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.descrizione);
        TextView mySubTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.subTitle);

        myImage.setImageResource(images[position]);
        myOptions.setText(title[position]);
        mySubTitle.setText(subTitle[position]);


        return row;
    }




}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


}
```

And this is the log

```
10-15 17:40:47.677: E/AndroidRuntime(5237): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-15 17:40:47.677: E/AndroidRuntime(5237): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-15 17:40:47.677: E/AndroidRuntime(5237):     at com.example.nevianoapp.CategoryMenu$ParserTask.onPostExecute(CategoryMenu.java:298)
10-15 17:40:47.677: E/AndroidRuntime(5237):     at com.example.nevianoapp.CategoryMenu$ParserTask.onPostExecute(CategoryMenu.java:1)
10-15 17:40:47.677: E/AndroidRuntime(5237):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
10-15 17:40:47.677: E/AndroidRuntime(5237):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
10-15 17:40:47.677: E/AndroidRuntime(5237):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
10-15 17:40:47.677: E/AndroidRuntime(5237):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-15 17:40:47.677: E/AndroidRuntime(5237):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-15 17:40:47.677: E/AndroidRuntime(5237):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-15 17:40:47.677: E/AndroidRuntime(5237):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-15 17:40:47.677: E/AndroidRuntime(5237):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-15 17:40:47.677: E/AndroidRuntime(5237):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-15 17:40:47.677: E/AndroidRuntime(5237):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-15 17:40:47.677: E/AndroidRuntime(5237):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Did anybody have the same problem?
I am really struggling

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

currently you have following issues in `ParserTask` class:

**1.** forget to initialize `test` List before calling clear or adding element to list

**2.**  using non initialized  instance of `adapter` because you are creating another instance of Adapter with same name inside `onCreate`.

```
adapter = new NewAdapter(this, opzioni, images, distance); //<<
l.setAdapter(adapter);
l.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting this. Do I have to initialize the same adapter inside of ParserTask?

Answer (score 0):

@Michael Corleone, I have had a similar problem few days ago. The problem was: when you call a AsyncTask, your main code is still running.

To "solve" this I usually use two activities and a AsyncTask class.

So, my first activity calls startActivityForResult().

The second activity send a ProgressDialog and other data to my AsyncTask. Then, after the doInBackground() execution the onPostExecute() is called, I close the ProgressDialog and set the RESULT for the second Activity as "OK" or "CANCELED". In both cases I dismiss the ProgressDialog and finish() the second Activity.

The first Activity receives the second one result and I do wherever I need. I hope it helps you.

Comment: I got the idea! I want to see if I can find a more elegant way to get around this, otherwise I'll try this. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you could fix this issue or not. Anyway, today I found out a way to do what you want.

1. First you have to create a constructor method in your AsyncTask that receives an Activity as parameter. In this constructor you'll set the context with the received Activity.
2. In the Activity that will call the AsyncTask you create a public method to update the data in your view.
3. The AsyncTask class needs to have a particular instance of all the activities that will call the AsyncTask (but you don't have to initialize them all);
4. In the doInBackground() method you must initialize the Object with the data you'll use after the execution;
5. In the onPostExecute() method you must verify which activity called the task, and set the new data to your view.

See:

```
public class AnyActivity extends Activity {
    TextView txView;

    //onCreate...
    //onPause...
    //onResume...

    public updateData(Object object) {
    //update the data in the UI
    }
}


public class WSCallSoap extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Boolean> {

    AnyActivity anyActivity;
    Activity activity;
    DataModelClass dmc;
    private ProgressDialog dialog = null;

    public WSCallSoap (Activity activity){
        this.activity = activity;
        Context context = activity;
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    }

    public void onPreExecute(){
        this.dialog.setMessage("Sending");
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    public boolean doInBackground(Object... params){
        dmc = ... //initialize the object and do wherever you need
    }

    public void onPostExecute(boolean success) {

        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

        if (activity.class == AnyActivity.class) {
            anyActivity.updateData(dmc);
        }
    }

}
```